# How to cluster data that has been split into a binary vector based on their path with scikitlearn?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a very large list of URLs, and I want to group them based on their similarity to one another for later uses. I have already grouped them based on their domain. I tried to look at their paths and file. However, the method I used to do this took to long because it iterated through every character in the word.

I now have split up every url's path into the words that make it up, and put them into a data frame. The data frame's columns have every unique word that appears in a URL's path, and every row is filled out with 0s and 1s, based on whether the word appears or not. I thought that a good way to group them would be to use this data frame with scikit learn so that i can use KMeans.

Edit:

```
|                         | r | Python | EvE | Submit |
|-------------------------|---|--------|-----|--------|
| reddit.com/r/Python     | 1 | 1      | 0   | 0      |
| reddit.com/r/Eve        | 1 | 0      | 1   | 0      |
| reddit.com/r/Eve/Submit | 1 | 0      | 1   | 1      |
```

Comment: This thread may be interesting for you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86318/clustering-a-binary-matrix

Comment: Can you show an example?(e.g your data or some features)

Comment: @Masoud edited OP to have the table

Comment: @Gor1999 OK. it's good, so what is the problem?